# selecting options from another form

Tags: plugins, options

```
    Notice: wpdb::prepare was called incorrectly. The query argument of wpdb::prepare() must have a placeholder. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.9.0.) in /home/****/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5167
    
    Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /home/****/public_html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1310
function branch_students(){
       $content='';
$content.='<div class="container">';
$content.='<h1 align=center class="fofa">Enter Branch</h1>';
$content.='<form method="post" >';
$content.='<div class="b2">';
$content.='<input type="text" name="branch" id="branch" class="box" placeholder="Enter Branch" required */></div>';
$content.='<br>';
$content.='<div>';
$content.='<button type="submit" name="save" class="btn_Register" value="save">Save</button>';
$content.='</div>';
$content.='</form>';
$content.='</div>';
return $content;
}
this is my first form in this form i creates branches. now i want database of this branch form should be showed in the following table as selection options.
function arsh_forms(){
$content .='<div class="col-sm-6">';
$content .='<label class="fofa"  style=" font: italic bold 12px/30px Georgia, serif; font-size:26px;color:black;">Select Branch</label>';
  $content .='<select  name="selectbranch"id="selectbranch"  class="form-control"style=" font: italic bold 12px/30px Georgia, serif; font-size:20px;"placeholder="selectbranch"required/>';
    $content .='<option value="0" >select branch</option>';
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name=$wpdb->prefix.'arsh_branch';
    $select_branch = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table_name"));
    if(count($select_branch) > 0){
        foreach ($select_branch as $key=>$value){
          
            $content .='<option value="<?php echo $value->branches; ?>">
                <?php echo ucwords($value->branches);?></option>';
            
        }
        
    }
    
          $content .='</select>';
$content.='<div class="col-sm-6">';
$content .='<button type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" style=" width:30%;height:35px;background-color:black;color:white;float:right; margin-top:40px;" 
class="bt">Register</button>';
      $content .='</div>';
}
```

i think now it is understandable.plz if anybody can help me?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: i want  to add select option in my form and i added items in other form but it should showed on this form as selecting items.

Comment: Nothing included in the question is remotely useful in understanding your issue (what's the other form? how is it saved?), and I can't see what it has to do with WordPress either.

Comment: Although I have given an answer on what I believe is incorrect in your code. I do agree with Jacob, that, the question should be clearly written here with more details to allow people to answer. You can still edit the question and update it so that if someone else stumbles here, they can get a better understanding of it as well

Answer (score 0):

In the following line: `$select_branch = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table_name"));`, you are using `$wpdb->prepare`incorrectly. `wpdb::prepare` needs two arguments, first one is a Query string with sprintf like placeholders and second an array of the values to to substitute the placeholders. More details [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/). And that is the error you are getting as posted on top of your question.

Comment: ok thanks i will try

Answer (score 0):

```
yeah i got answer 
$content .='<select  name="selectbranch"id="selectbranch"  class="form-control"style=" font: italic bold 12px/30px Georgia, serif; font-size:20px;"placeholder="selectbranch"required/>';
$content .='<option >select branch</option>';
global $wpdb;
$table_name=$wpdb->prefix.'arsh_branch';
$select_branch = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name");

if(count($select_branch) > 0){
    foreach ($select_branch as $key=>$value){
        
        $content .='<option value= "'.$value->branches.'">'
            .$value->branches.'</option>';
       
    }
    
}


      $content .='</select>';
```